# Create table with for loop

Tags: javascript

I tried to rewrite this code using the for loop, but the lines of code were displayed incorrectly, what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/tsnL87jk/1/

```
var table = "<table border='1' width='100%' height='300px'>";
var tr=1;
while(tr<=10){
    table+="<tr>";
    var td=1;
    while(td<=10){
        var x = tr * td;
        if(td%2==0)
            table+="<td style='background-color:red;'>"+x+"</td>";
        else
            table+="<td style='background-color:green;'>"+x+"</td>";
        td++;
    }
    table+="</tr>";
    tr++;
}
table+="</table>";

document.write(table);

var table = "<table border='1' width='100%' height='300px'>";
var tr = 1;

for (tr=1; tr <= 10; tr++) {
    table += "<tr>";

    for ( var td=1; td <= 10; td++) {
        var x = tr * td;
        if (td % 2 == 0) {
            table += "<td style='background-color:red;'>" + x + "</td>";
        } else {
            table += "<td style='background-color:green;'>" + x + "</td>";
        }
    }
    table+="</tr>";
}

table += "</table>";
document.write(table);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7x5h6k2z/

Comment: If you explain what you're trying to achieve it would help people understand better how to help. What precisely is wrong with the output?

Comment: sounds like he wants to just converting the way he iterates.   @atamata I would suggest reading how for-loops and while loops work, and then when you have specific questions, we can answer them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fiddles you linked to are anything to go by then the first for loop should be ...

```
for (tr=1; tr <= 100; tr++)
```